# C# ListView newly added item does not show correct data

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

My program reads an XML file for movies, and shows the data using a class called Movie and a list called movieList. You are able to display the information of a selected one, add one and modify/delete.

[Data display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lian0.png)

The information displaying works just fine, however when I add a new item and select it, the data shown is the exact same as the 1st movie in the list. If I add another movie, it will show the same data as the 2nd movie. The only time the program will show the correct info for the newly added movies is if I close the program and reopen it. I've tried many things but none have really worked out. The ListView display is fine, but getting the actual data from the selected item in the movieList is not. Method appendNodeToXML works as intended for writing the inputted data and transferring it to the XML file. Feels like it could just be a simple fix.

[Incorrect data display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wrdm.png)

Code:

```
private void MovieListView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //  If an item is selected
            if (movieListView.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                //  Declare index selected from ListView to variable
                int selectedIndex = movieListView.SelectedIndices[0];
                Movie selectedMovie = new Movie();
                selectedMovie = movieList[selectedIndex];

                //  Show index of selected item
                titleMovieTextBox.Text = selectedMovie.Title;
                genreMovieTextBox.Text = selectedMovie.Genre;
                yearMovieTextBox.Text = selectedMovie.Year.ToString();
                lengthMovieTextBox.Text = selectedMovie.Length;
                directorMovieTextBox.Text = selectedMovie.Director;
                ratingMovieTextBox.Text = selectedMovie.Rating.ToString();
                imageMovieTextBox.Text = selectedMovie.ImagePath;

            }

private void AddMovieButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (genreAddMovieTextBox.Text != "" || titleAddMovieTextBox.Text != "" || yearAddMovieTextBox.Text != "" || lengthAddMovieTextBox.Text != ""
                || directorAddMovieTextBox.Text != "" || ratingAddMovieTextBox.Text != "" || imagePathAddMovieTextBox.Text != "")
            {
                //  Clear ListView to prepare for new added item
                movieListView.Items.Clear();

                //  Method to append all movie nodes to the XML file
                appendNodeToXMLFile("movies.xml");

                //  Indicate what XML file to read
                readXMLFile("movies.xml");

                //  Method to clear TextBoxes
                ClearTextBoxes();

                // Set focus
                genreAddMovieTextBox.Focus();

                // Refresh genre
                GetGenre();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Not all entries are filled.");
            }
        }

        private void appendNodeToXMLFile(string filePath)
        {
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

            if (File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                //  XML file loaded
                xmlDoc.Load(filePath);

                //  rootNode to memory
                XmlElement rootNode = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;

                //  XML nodes created for movie and its attributes
                XmlElement addMovie = xmlDoc.CreateElement("movie");
                XmlElement addTitle = xmlDoc.CreateElement("title");
                XmlElement addYear = xmlDoc.CreateElement("year");
                XmlElement addLength = xmlDoc.CreateElement("length");
                XmlElement addDirector = xmlDoc.CreateElement("director");
                XmlElement addRating = xmlDoc.CreateElement("audienceRating");
                XmlElement addImagePath = xmlDoc.CreateElement("imageFilePath");

                //  Create textNode element
                XmlText newTextNode;

                //  Set attribute for genre from TextBox
                addMovie.SetAttribute("genre", genreAddMovieTextBox.Text);

                //  Use new node for title
                newTextNode = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode(titleAddMovieTextBox.Text);

                //  Add inputted information to text node
                addTitle.AppendChild(newTextNode);

                //  Use new node for year
                newTextNode = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode(yearAddMovieTextBox.Text);

                //  Add inputted information to text node
                addYear.AppendChild(newTextNode);

                //  Use new node for length
                newTextNode = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode(lengthAddMovieTextBox.Text);

                //  Add inputted information to text node
                addLength.AppendChild(newTextNode);

                //  Use new node for director
                newTextNode = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode(directorAddMovieTextBox.Text);

                //  Add inputted information to text node
                addDirector.AppendChild(newTextNode);

                //  Use new node for director
                newTextNode = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode(ratingAddMovieTextBox.Text);

                //  Add inputted information to text node
                addRating.AppendChild(newTextNode);

                //  Use new node for director
                newTextNode = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode(imagePathAddMovieTextBox.Text);

                //  Add inputted information to text node
                addImagePath.AppendChild(newTextNode);


                //  Send each movie attribute to addMovie node
                addMovie.AppendChild(addTitle);
                addMovie.AppendChild(addYear);
                addMovie.AppendChild(addLength);
                addMovie.AppendChild(addDirector);
                addMovie.AppendChild(addRating);
                addMovie.AppendChild(addImagePath);

                //  Send movie node to main movies node
                rootNode.AppendChild(addMovie);

                //  Save file
                xmlDoc.Save(filePath);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The file " + filePath + " does not exist.");
            }
        }
```

Comment: How is the movie data initially put into the `ListBox`? How is the `ListBox` updated after a new movie is added? What happens in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event when you trace the code after a new movie is added?

Comment: The data is read from a method to read the XML file specified. The ListView updates with the add button clearing the ListView, calling method appendNodeToXMLFile which is what adds the new entry in the movies.XML, then recalls readXML() to populate the movieListView. SelectedIndexChanged just checks what item is chosen and presents its info in the form.

Comment: Well… have you put a break-point in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event and trace what happens when a new movie is added?